# Can you help me with this MDX query?

Tags: mdx

Pivot Report Filters and corresponding values:

Forecast Version is April Forecast (therefore, just 1 value),
Rev Sum Category is All (therefore, no filter), except for 2 values, how do I write that expression?

Rev Sum Product Summary is one value,
Region is All (therefore, no filter),

The following 3 are the fields that should be filtered on All except for 2 values, how do I write that expression?

Sale Type is Multiple Items (therefore, many values),
Marketing Program is Multiple Items (therefore, many values),
Product Family is Multiple Items (therefore, many values)

In the pivot table layout, the Row Label is the `RevSumCategory`, and the column label is the measure, which is the no. of Sell Thru Licenses – Actual.
What I want to create, is an MDX query in its simplest form possible, that would generate the same results as show in the pivot table. The code should be simple enough for any user of the report, given the right access, to be able to modify field values.
Notice that in pivot report filters, there are (4) fields which aren’t “All” but are filtered.

My questions are:

(a) How do I include in the MDX query the pivot report filters?

(b) How do I write an MDX query expression that filters on a field which has all but 2 values.

When the filter is just 2 values, it is easy enough, I can include the 2 values for that field, e.g.

```
[Business].[Business Summary].&[Field],[Business].[Business Summary].&   
[Stores Field],
```

But when the filter is everything (all) except 2 values, I can’t write it the same way because then the expression for that field would be far too long.

My query code (in progress) is below.

```
Select NON EMPTY [Measures].[Sell Thru Licenses - Actual]  on Columns,
{[Product].[Rev Sum Category].&[value 1], [Product].[Rev Sum Category].&  
[value 2]}) ON ROWS  

From [Cube]

WHERE 
([Forecast Version].[Forecast Version].&[April Forecast],
[Product].[Rev Sum Category].[All],
[Business].[Business Summary].&[Field],[Business].[Business Summary].&    
[Stores Field],
[Product].[Rev Sum Product Summary].&[One Value],
[Geography].[Region].[All],
[Sale Type].[Sale Type].[this is the field that has multiple values]
```

Hoping someone can help me write the code just for the field that has multiple values. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your WHERE clause does *not* work, as you use the tuple syntax, which only allows one member per hierarchy, not two as you have for `Business Summary`. I will come to that later, and first concentrate on your main question about a negative/exception filter:
You can write a "negative filter" as follows:

```
[Sale Type].[Sale Type].Members - { [Sale Type].[Sale Type].&[A], [Sale Type].[Sale Type].&[B] }
```

if you want to exclude members `A` and `B`.

Note, however, that this is now a set and not a single member, hence the notation in the WHERE clause gets slightly more complicated, as you cannot use the simple tuple notation, you would use the crossjoin operator `*`:

```
...
WHERE 
([Forecast Version].[Forecast Version].&[April Forecast],
[Product].[Rev Sum Category].[All],
[Business].[Business Summary].&[Field], // note there is only one member here
[Product].[Rev Sum Product Summary].&[One Value],
[Geography].[Region].[All])
*
([Sale Type].[Sale Type].Members - { [Sale Type].[Sale Type].&[A], [Sale Type].[Sale Type].&[B] })
```

And a finally, you can use the same approach of a cross join of sets to also resolve your multi selection problem: You could write the filter condition as

```
...
WHERE 
{[Forecast Version].[Forecast Version].&[April Forecast]}
*
{[Business].[Business Summary].&[Field],[Business].[Business Summary].&    
[Stores Field]}
*
{[Product].[Rev Sum Product Summary].&[One Value]}
*
([Sale Type].[Sale Type].Members - { [Sale Type].[Sale Type].&[A], [Sale Type].[Sale Type].&[B] })
```

I simplified it, assuming that your cube has the standard definition of the All members being the default members of their hierarchies, and thus they can be omitted in the WHERE condition.